# Видео очень сильно замедляет скорость загрузки сайта

Tags: html, youtube

На сайте есть видео и оно очень сильно замедляет скорость загрузки сайта. Как сделать так, чтобы видео не загружалось вместе с сайтом, а загружалось только тогда, когда на него нажимает пользователь?

Comment: Откуда тянется видео?

Comment: Загружается с YouTube

Comment: пример кода есть какой-то?

Comment: Здесь обычны код для вставки видео:
    <iframe  id="video" width="100%" 
    height="100%"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mOqFRuRNt8s" 
    frameborder="0"></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример уже где-то приводил:

```js
var video_player = function(config) { 
 
 var wrapper = document.getElementById('Wrapper'),
  playlist = document.getElementById('Playlist'),
  video_name;
 
 for (video_name in config.video_list) {
  playlist.innerHTML +=  '<div class="playlist-item" data-link="' + config.video_list[video_name] + '">' + video_name + '</div>';
 }
 this.play_button = document.querySelectorAll('.playlist-item');
 this.add = function(){
  var video_link = this.getAttribute('data-link');
  var el = document.getElementById('Iframe_window');
  
  //Avoid button click to re upload same video
  if(el && el.getAttribute("src") == video_link){
   return;
  }
  //If we dont have an Iframe element, create a new one and aplly link to a video
  if(!el) {
   var iframe_create = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
   wrapper.appendChild(iframe_create);
   iframe_create.setAttribute("src", video_link);
   iframe_create.id = 'Iframe_window';
  }
  //If we have it - change the link to it.
  else {   
   el.setAttribute("src", video_link);
  }
  
 }
 for (var i=0; i < this.play_button.length; i++) {
  this.play_button[i].addEventListener('click', this.add); 
 } 
}

      
var play_it = new video_player({
 video_list : {
  'First interesting movie' : 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/6GhPgnpl5Vs',
  'The second one' : 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/yl1PS0F7tVk',
  'The last in the show' : 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q1E8gruS5e4'
 }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gidugu");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: 'Gidugu', sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 60px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.wrapper iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.wrapper .playlist-item {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin: 2px 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 300ms;
}
.wrapper .playlist-item:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper" class="wrapper">
 <div id="Playlist" class="playlist">
 </div>
</div>
```

Пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/JWOgwJ)